# Finding median word length of text file with multiple lines

Tags: java, file-io

I have a text file, and I want to find the middle word of the whole file and print the number of characters it has. I can do this for one line:

```
 System.out.println("'" + str[tok / 2] + "'");
```

But I don't know how to point to a certain line. Here is all of my code:

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AmendClassify {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String file = sc.next();
        file = file + ".txt";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));

        System.out.println("You are scanning '" + file + "'");

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));

        double lineNum = 0;
        double wordCount = 0;
        double charCount = 0;
        int tok = 0;
        String str[] = null;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

        String line = null;
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
          line = s.nextLine();
          lineNum++;

          str = line.split((" "));
          tok = str.length;
          for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str[i].length() > 0) {
              wordCount++;
            }
          }
          charCount += (line.length());
        }
        double density = (charCount / wordCount);


        System.out.println("'" + str[tok / 2] + "'"); // middle word of the 1st/last line

        gap();
        System.out.println("Number of lines: " + lineNum);
        System.out.println("Number of words: " + wordCount);
        System.out.println("Number of characters: " + charCount);
        gap();
        System.out.println("The DENSITY of the text is: " + df.format(density));
        System.out.println();

        int critical;
        System.out.println("Do you want to alter the critical value(Y/N)");
        String answer = sc.next();

        if (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y")) {
          System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");
          critical = sc.nextInt();
        } else {
          critical = 6;
        }

        //So...
        if (density > critical) {
          System.out.println("NAME: '" + file + "'" + ", DENSITY: " + df.format(density) + ", TYPE: " + "Heavy");
        } else {
          System.out.println("NAME: '" + file + "'" + ", DENSITY: " + df.format(density) + ", TYPE: " + "Light");
        }

        System.out.print("--FINISHED--");
        s.close();
        output.close();
        sc.close();

      } //end of try
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid file name");
      }
    } // end of main

  public static void gap() {
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
  }
}
```

A text file I have used to test is

`Hello my name is Harry. This line contains 83 characters, 15  words, and 1 line(s).`
`This is the second line.`

`This is the third line.`

`This is the fourth line.`

Comment: The edge case which immediately pops into my head is a text file which has an even number of words.  How will you handle this case?  Statisticians would likely just take the mean of the middle 2 words.

Comment: But how do you link the lines together to form 1 large string, as at the moment I am scanning each line in individually and counting the number of characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this looks like a homework assignment I'd recommend reading the entire file into a `String` and then removing all new-line characters with `replaceAll()` if need be (depending how you read the entire file into a `String`). You then would effectively have a single line ... so your existing code would work (taking into account that the *middle* word would actually be the word to the left of the middle if the file has an even number of words).

Note that this is not an optimal solution though. Don't use it at work.